# Can anybody help identify this uniform ? Circa WW1

Tags: military, world-war-one, identification, uniform

I presume this photo is circa WW1. Can anybody identify which unit, regiment and rank, this would be very helpful.

[image: Two men with swords. Each wears a tunic with extensive horizontal braiding and complex braid on the sleeve. Each wears knee high boots and flat caps.]

Comment: Could we strive for a higher standard of friendly/welcoming for new users?   In particular I'm not sure that "useless questions" is really the tone we're seeking. I think H:SE has a pretty good record of helping out with uniform identification.

Comment: I’ll take that on board but check the quality of the last n Id questions. They are nearly indifferentiable by title or body text. There is no search depth for what has been done. And questions of identical quality are increasing

Comment: Looks like a German Hussar uniform, as seen on http://www.kaisersbunker.com/gtp/husar.htm

Comment: Those are valid and important issues. I'm constantly struggling to navigate between "friendly" and "quality"; we need to find a way to educate new users on our norms (searchability, preliminary, image descriptions).  If it were an easy problem, someone would have already solved it...

Comment: @kimchilover Looks good. The possible [pistol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreyse_M1907) might help narrow the date somewhat.

Comment: By take on board I mean grapple with it hard especially the positivity. I acknowledge I got negatively spaced and may have badly impacted new users and provided a negative model.

Answer (score 8):

This is a partial answer.  This looks like a German Hussar uniform, as shown on the web [page](http://www.kaisersbunker.com/gtp/husar.htm).  This style of jacket (called an "Atilla") seems to be a distinct part of the uniform of Hussars.  The cap badge is distinctly German. But the German Army had many Hussar regiments, and I don't know how to tell the rank.  Their youthful appearance, and the lack of extra decoration, make me think the two figures in the photo were relatively junior in rank.

Comment: There is a book on this topic: https://www.abebooks.com/9780764320613/Uniforms-Accoutrements-Imperial-German-Hussars-0764320610/plp

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the same one at West Point.
https://history.army.mil/museums/IMCOM/westPoint/index.html

very bottom of the page, on the right.

[image]

Comment: So what is the answer?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the West Point Museum display in question is of German Hussar uniforms.  The emblem on the cap is very clear, for instance.

Comment: These are 'history of warfare' objects on display. *Not* Westpoint's own uniforms.